# How to use finite difference method for non-uniform grid in python?

Tags: python, derivative, finite-difference

I have a function `f = dp/de` (variation in pressure as a function of variation in energy) and I would like to calculate this derivative with finite differences. I have a list for the `p` values ​​and a list for the `e` values. However, the grid formed by interpolating `p` with `e` is not uniform.

I tried, earlier, to calculate f as follows:

```
f.append((p[i+1] - p[i])/(e[i+1]- e[i]))
```

However, I need a better refinement at least in the first points.

How can I use finite difference method for non-uniform grids in python? Basically the grid has this format below (photo)

[grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyb2P.jpg)

Comment: Could you use interpolation? Most of the scipy interpolators, e.g. [CubicSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline) have a `derivative` method that allows you to calculate derivatives at any location.

Answer (score 0):

I have a python library named [uts](https://github.com/mariolpantunes/uts) (uneven time series) that allows one to compute the central differences for the first and second order.
The code that matters is [here](https://github.com/mariolpantunes/uts/blob/main/uts/gradient.py).